# Airflow SimpleHttpOperator is not pushing to xcom

Tags: python, airflow

I have the following SimpleHttpOperator inside my dag:

```
extracting_user = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='extracting_user',
        http_conn_id='user_api',
        endpoint='api/', # Some Api already configured and checked
        method="GET",
        response_filter=lambda response: json.loads(response.text),
        log_response=True,
        do_xcom_push=True,
    )
```

followed by a PythonOperator:

```
processing_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id='processing_user',
        python_callable=_processing_user
    )
```

The function:

```
def _processing_user(ti):
    users = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=['extracting_user'])
    if not len(users) or 'results' not in users[0]:
        raise ValueError(f'User is empty')

    **More function code**
```

When I execute `airflow tasks test myDag extracting_user 2022-03-02` followed by `airflow tasks test myDag processing_user 2022-03-02` I get the value error with users variable equals to an empty array.

I have tested extracting_user task alone and it gets the desired data from the API. I have already queried with sqlite xcom and it is an empty table.

I am using airflow 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem changing to the version 2.0.0 of airflow. It seems that the SimpleHttpOperator doesn't store the request response on the xcom table on 2.3.0 version

Answer (score 0):

the SimpleHttpOperator does return a XCOM. However, the command airflow tasks test does NOT create XComs anymore, whe